# Adding parameters to request then get them doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I have Laravel project and in this project I have to create Request object to use it like this:

`$request = new Request();`
I tried to add from and to dates like this:

`$request->request->add([from'=>$from_temp,'to'=>$to_temp]);`

when I dd the request it gives me that from and to are exist(image)
[image for request Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBbvz.png)
but when I try to access them using
`request('from')`
it gives me null

I don't know what's going on

Thank you

Comment: `$request->merge([...])`

Comment: Also null
I've tried it before and it worked but in this time the object doesn't come from the front or API, in this time I am creating the object in the backend like I said

Comment: The response from @lagbox is the correct one. use the merge to add the attributes to the $request.
Your method is adding the array to the request but not parametersBag per your screen shot. This may help https://medium.com/@kheme/how-to-merge-new-values-into-an-array-request-on-laravel-c7e852d4f394

Comment: this also doesn't helped me, what helped was the comment of @thefallen on his answer

Answer (score 0):

`request('from')` helper will pull values form the global request object, not from the `$request` variable that you created. What you want to to is use `$request->get('from')`

Comment: could you tell me how to set he global request object?

Comment: I can't use get, because there are more than one function I want to use, all of them are working on request('from'), I can't change the code entirely, so if there is a solution to set the global request object will be great –

Comment: @bluearrow can you try `request()->merge(['from'=>$from_temp,'to'=>$to_temp])` and then `request('from')`?

Comment: than you so much @thefallen
this helped